# Get current time in seconds since the Epoch on Linux, Bash

Tags: linux, bash, datetime

I need something simple like `date`, but in seconds since 1970 instead of the current date, hours, minutes, and seconds.

`date` doesn't seem to offer that option. Is there an easy way?

Comment: Some versions of date have it and some don't. So it's not always present.  I ran 'type -a date' and used a different version and that worked.

Comment: FWIW, Ubuntu only has /bin/date, for which @Steef's answer works

Comment: @TheBonsai that's not part of the POSIX standard version of the 'date' tool. Just because your version has it (probably GNU), you shouldn't assume everyone's implementations do.

Answer (score 1629, accepted):

This should work:

```
date +%s
```

As recently corrected in the [date manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html):

> %s = seconds since the Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00 UTC)

Comment: the date manpge should be changed from `%s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` to `%s     seconds since the epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` because I missed it in there.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.
man date does not show %s.
I must have a very old version of bash (3.2.51(1) for Solaris)?

Comment: @livefree75 `date` is not built into `bash`, so your version of `bash` has nothing to do with which `date` implementation your system ships with.

Comment: And if you want the fractions of a second, to nine decimal places, use: `date +%s.%N`

Comment: For milliseconds use `date +%s%3N`

Comment: how do I get the local time?

Comment: ⚠️ A better epoch may be **UTC**: `date --utc +'%s'`

Comment: @AlbertoSalviaNovella On my systems (all Debian Bullseye), both variants output the same value. However, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Binarus Yes, my comment was due to an error in the man-page. As pointed out in devin's comment. Both solutions are the same.

Answer (score 188):

Just to add.
Get the seconds since epoch(Jan 1 1970) for any given date(e.g Oct 21 1973).

```
date -d "Oct 21 1973" +%s
```

Convert the number of seconds back to date

```
date --date @120024000
```

The command `date` is pretty versatile. Another cool thing you can do with date(shamelessly copied from `date --help`).
  Show the local time for 9AM next Friday on the west coast of the US

```
date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" 09:00 next Fri'
```

Better yet, take some time to read the man page 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html

Comment: This is not the OP's question, but it answers mine, so +1 from me.

Comment: Maybe it's the version of `date` or because I'm using `zsh` (macOS Catalina) but this doesn't work for me. Running `$ date -d "Oct 21 1973" +%s` outputs `usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: @JoshuaPinter and others on macOS, I had the same question. `man date` shows that the option(s) used to parse another date string are `-j` and `-f expectedformat` on macOS. (`-d` is used to set daylight savings.)

Comment: The `date` command above is from **gnu coreutils** pacakge. On mac, **gnu coreutils** package can be installed with [brew](https://brew.sh) or [macports](https://www.macports.org/). After installing, the binary is named as `gdate` to distinguish it from macOS's preinstalled `/bin/date`

Comment: @JoshuaPinter use ```date -r 120024000```

Answer (score 103):

## Pure bash solution

Since `bash` 5.0 ([released on 7 Jan 2019](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2019-01/msg00010.html)) you can use the built-in variable `EPOCHSECONDS`.

```
$ echo $EPOCHSECONDS
1547624774
```

There is also `EPOCHREALTIME` which includes fractions of seconds.

```
$ echo $EPOCHREALTIME
1547624774.371210
```

`EPOCHREALTIME` can be converted to micro-seconds (μs) by removing the decimal point (or comma, if your locale is French, German, etc.) This might be of interest when using `bash`'s built-in arithmetic `(( expression ))` which can only handle integers.

```
$ echo ${EPOCHREALTIME/[^0-9]/}
1547624774371210
```

In all examples from above the printed time values are equal for better readability. In reality the time values would differ since each command takes a small amount of time to be executed.

Comment: For millisecond resolution (same format as `date +%s%3N`) you can use `echo $(( ${EPOCHREALTIME/./} / 1000 ))`

Answer (score 62):

So far, all the answers use the external program `date`.

Since Bash 4.2, `printf` has a new modifier `%(dateformat)T` that, when used with argument `-1` outputs the current date with format given by `dateformat`, handled by `strftime(3)` (`man 3 strftime` for informations about the formats).

So, for a pure Bash solution:

```
printf '%(%s)T\n' -1
```

or if you need to store the result in a variable `var`:

```
printf -v var '%(%s)T' -1
```

No external programs and no subshells!

Since Bash 4.3, it's even possible to not specify the `-1`:

```
printf -v var '%(%s)T'
```

(but it might be wiser to always give the argument `-1` nonetheless).

If you use `-2` as argument instead of `-1`, Bash will use the time the shell was started instead of the current date.  This can be used to compute elapsed times

```
$ printf -v beg '%(%s)T\n' -2
$ printf -v now '%(%s)T\n' -1
$ echo beg=$beg now=$now elapsed=$((now-beg))
beg=1583949610 now=1583953032 elapsed=3422
```

Comment: You want to use `-2` in case you have a longer running job (think of a script to control you backups) and send a mail in the end "Backup started at $somewhen completed at $now" - which can be accomplished with `-2` avoiding to store a dedicated variable at the beginning.

Answer (score 55):

With most Awk implementations:

```
awk 'BEGIN {srand(); print srand()}'
```

Comment: Wow that is obscure

Comment: Wow, had to go look this one up. This is a pragmatic solution, but not necessarily good/portable. [It seems that implementations of awk `srand()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html) are typically seeded with the current date/time. The second call to `srand()` returns the value previously used as the seed.

Comment: POSIX compliant as well, because this is how NAWK behaves.  Very nice.  I was trying to remember this one and tracked down your post.  Thanks.

Comment: Would it be wrong of me to suggest awk 'BEGIN {print srand(srand())}'

Answer (score 24):

This is an extension to what @pellucide has done, but for Macs:

To determine the number of seconds since epoch (Jan 1 1970) for any given date (e.g. Oct 21 1973)

```
$ date -j -f "%b %d %Y %T" "Oct 21 1973 00:00:00" "+%s"
120034800
```

Please note, that for completeness, I have added the time part to the format. The reason being is that `date` will take whatever date part you gave it and add the *current* time to the value provided. For example, if you execute the above command at 4:19PM, without the '00:00:00' part, it will add the time automatically. Such that "Oct 21 1973" will be parsed as "Oct 21 1973 16:19:00". That may not be what you want.

To convert your timestamp back to a date:

```
$ date -j -r 120034800
Sun Oct 21 00:00:00 PDT 1973
```

Apple's man page for the date implementation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html

Comment: To be clear, this is for BSD's `date` command, whereas any solutions suggesting `date -d` are for GNU `date`. BSD date in macOS [comes from FreeBSD](https://man.freebsd.org/date), and shares a number of options with NetBSD and OpenBSD. And this is ***entirely separate*** from bash.

Comment: the `%N` option mentioned for fractional seconds in gnu date is missing from MacOS date.  On 10.14, none of the formats are in the man page; they're in the `strftime(3)` man page, which you won't have if you don't have Xcode installed, and might not see with man command even if you do.

Comment: By extension of @ghoti's comment, this works on MacOS.

Answer (score 3):

use this bash script (my `~/bin/epoch`):

```
#!/bin/bash

# get seconds since epoch
test "x$1" == x && date +%s && exit 0

# or convert epoch seconds to date format (see "man date" for options)
EPOCH="$1"
shift
date -d @"$EPOCH" "$@"
```