# Subtract two variables in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the script below to subtract the counts of files between two directories but the `COUNT=` expression does not work. What is the correct syntax?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FIRSTV=`ls -1 | wc -l`
cd ..
SECONDV=`ls -1 | wc -l`
COUNT=expr $FIRSTV-$SECONDV  ## -> gives 'command not found' error
echo $COUNT
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add numbers in a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902/how-can-i-add-numbers-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You just need a little extra whitespace around the minus sign, and backticks:

```
COUNT=`expr $FIRSTV - $SECONDV`
```

Be aware of the exit status:

The exit status is 0 if EXPRESSION is neither null nor 0, **1 if EXPRESSION is null or 0**.

Keep this in mind when using the expression in a bash script in combination with **set -e** which will exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

Comment: This answer also works in posix `sh` shell. For portability, you may want to use this answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that according to Shellcheck, expr is a codesmell due to it being antiquated and difficult to use: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2003

Comment: I concur; Anubhava's answer should be the accepted one. `expr` only makes sense if you need compatibility back to the dark ages when Solaris `sh` was popular and HP-UX and AIX were still a thing. POSIX `sh` too has supported arithmetic expressions for many years now.

Answer (score 452):

Try this Bash syntax instead of trying to use an external program `expr`:

```
count=$((FIRSTV-SECONDV))
```

BTW, the correct syntax of using `expr` is:

```
count=$(expr $FIRSTV - $SECONDV)
```

But keep in mind using `expr` is going to be slower than the internal Bash syntax I provided above.

Comment: This form is magnitudes quicker than using the expr external program.

Comment: This works without the backticks, but may I know why? +1 for the answe.r

Comment: Thanks. Backtick is old shell syntax. BASH supports new `$(command)` syntax for command substitution. Also since BASH support arithmetic operations in `$(( ... ))` it is better to not to use an external utility `expr`

Comment: I never new you could reference variables without the "$", very interesting. This works on Ubuntu 12,14 just FYI.

Comment: @anubhava - Can you please explain the dollar with the double parenthesis notion? Thanks.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka: In bash `$(( ... ))` is use for evaluating arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 32):

You can use:

```
((count = FIRSTV - SECONDV))
```

to avoid invoking a separate process, as per the following transcript:

```
pax:~$ FIRSTV=7
pax:~$ SECONDV=2
pax:~$ ((count = FIRSTV - SECONDV))
pax:~$ echo $count
5
```

Answer (score 17):

This is how I always do maths in Bash:

```
count=$(echo "$FIRSTV - $SECONDV"|bc)
echo $count
```

Comment: that's only necessary if you're dealing with floating point numbers.

Comment: I realise that, but I'd rather make a habit of catching those cases with a `|bc` type command than miss it once or twice. Different strokes for different folks as they say.

Comment: @glenn jackman but that's what I was searching without even knowing my decimals math were "floating point numbers". No other answer worked for me except this!

Answer (score 13):

White space is important, `expr` expects its operands and operators as separate arguments. You also have to capture the output. Like this:

```
COUNT=$(expr $FIRSTV - $SECONDV)
```

but it's more common to use the builtin arithmetic expansion:

```
COUNT=$((FIRSTV - SECONDV))
```

Answer (score 8):

For simple integer arithmetic, you can also use the builtin [let](http://ss64.com/bash/let.html) command.

```
 ONE=1
 TWO=2
 let "THREE = $ONE + $TWO"
 echo $THREE
    3
```

For more info on `let`, look [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#LETREF).

Comment: @another.anon.coward Your link's better than mine +1. (... and  stealing link)

Comment: Had a lot of trouble in getting this working. Finally this worked - `let "sanity_check_duration=sanity_check_duration_end_time_delay_sec - sanity_check_duration_start_time_delay_sec"` (removing dollar sign from variables)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the suggested 3 methods you can try [`let`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#LETREF) which carries out arithmetic operations on variables as follows:

`let COUNT=$FIRSTV-$SECONDV`

or

`let COUNT=FIRSTV-SECONDV`

Answer (score 0):

### Diff Real Positive Numbers

```
diff_real () {
  echo "df=($1 - $2); if (df < 0) { df=df* -1}; print df" | bc -l;
}
```

### Usage

```
var_a=10
var_b=4

output=$(diff_real $var_a $var_b)
# 6

#########


var_a=4
var_b=10

output=$(diff_real $var_a $var_b)
# 6
```

Answer (score -1):

Use BASH:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# home/victoria/test.sh

START=$(date +"%s")                                     ## seconds since Epoch
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
  sleep 1.5
  END=$(date +"%s")                                     ## integer
  TIME=$((END - START))                                 ## integer
  AVG_TIME=$(python -c "print(float($TIME/$i))")        ## int to float
  printf 'i: %i | elapsed time: %0.1f sec | avg. time: %0.3f\n' $i $TIME $AVG_TIME
  ((i++))                                               ## increment $i
done
```

**Output**

```
$ ./test.sh 
i: 1 | elapsed time: 1.0 sec | avg. time: 1.000
i: 2 | elapsed time: 3.0 sec | avg. time: 1.500
i: 3 | elapsed time: 5.0 sec | avg. time: 1.667
i: 4 | elapsed time: 6.0 sec | avg. time: 1.500
i: 5 | elapsed time: 8.0 sec | avg. time: 1.600
i: 6 | elapsed time: 9.0 sec | avg. time: 1.500
i: 7 | elapsed time: 11.0 sec | avg. time: 1.571
i: 8 | elapsed time: 12.0 sec | avg. time: 1.500
i: 9 | elapsed time: 14.0 sec | avg. time: 1.556
i: 10 | elapsed time: 15.0 sec | avg. time: 1.500
$
```

- [Get current time in seconds since the Epoch on Linux, Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092631/get-current-time-in-seconds-since-the-epoch-on-linux-bash)