# How can I do division with variables in a Linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, division

When I run commands in my shell as below, it returns an `expr: non-integer argument` error. Can someone please explain this to me?

```
$ x=20
$ y=5
$ expr x / y 
expr: non-integer argument
```

Comment: @ShivanRaptor While one might argue that the question is an RTFM question, it is certainly a valid shell programming question. It is also a reasonable question for someone coming from languages that don't require dereferencing (e.g. Ruby or JavaScript). It should be left open.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor No, this is on topic here. It's about programming in Bash. Unix/Linux is primarily for using the system, not programming. Now, shell scripting does span the boundary between programming and using the system, so this could be on topic on either site. If there were a question about "how do I set up networking", that would definitely belong on Unix/Linux. If it were a question about interactive keybindings in Bash, that would also belong there. But a question about shell scripting is definitely on topic here as well as there.

Comment: See my answer here, that illustrates subtraction and division of $BASH variables, using a call to Python from the shell (to convert int to float ...): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385627/subtract-two-variables-in-bash/55856163#55856163

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Those variables are shell variables.  To expand them as parameters to another program (*ie* `expr`), you need to use the `$` prefix:

```
expr $x / $y
```

The reason it complained is because it thought you were trying to operate on alphabetic characters (*ie* non-integer)

If you are using the Bash shell, you can achieve the same result using expression syntax:

```
echo $((x / y))
```

Or:

```
z=$((x / y))
echo $z
```

Comment: You can find out a lot by reading through the man-page for bash.  Type `man bash` at the prompt (`q` to exit)

Comment: It has to be noted somewhere on this page that most (if not all) GNU/Linux shells **only perform integer operations**.

Answer (score 47):

I believe it was already mentioned in other threads:

```
calc(){ awk "BEGIN { print "$*" }"; }
```

then you can simply type :

```
calc 7.5/3.2
  2.34375
```

In your case it will be:

```
x=20; y=3;
calc $x/$y
```

or if you prefer, add this as a separate script and make it available in $PATH so you will always have it in your local shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
calc(){ awk "BEGIN { print $* }"; }
```

Comment: You may also use
`echo '1 / 3' | bc -l`

Answer (score 26):

Why not use let; I find it much easier.
Here's an example you may find useful:

```
start=`date +%s`
# ... do something that takes a while ...
sleep 71

end=`date +%s`
let deltatime=end-start
let hours=deltatime/3600
let minutes=(deltatime/60)%60
let seconds=deltatime%60
printf "Time spent: %d:%02d:%02d\n" $hours $minutes $seconds
```

Another simple example - calculate number of days since 1970:

```
let days=$(date +%s)/86400
```

Answer (score 18):

### Referencing Bash Variables Requires Parameter Expansion

The default shell on most Linux distributions is Bash. In Bash, variables must use a dollar sign prefix for [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). For example:

```
x=20
y=5
expr $x / $y
```

Of course, Bash also has [arithmetic operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic) and a special [arithmetic expansion syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#Arithmetic-Expansion), so there's no need to invoke the *expr* binary as a separate process. You can let the shell do all the work like this:

```
x=20; y=5
echo $((x / y))
```

Comment: See [Arithmetic Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) and [Shell Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html) in the Bash Reference Manual for all the gory details.

Comment: This has nothing to do with _dereferencing_ but _interpolating_ and `expr` is discouraged in 2013.

Comment: @sputnick You are clearly confused. Please feel free to consult a dictionary. See [dereference](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Adereference) and [interpolate](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Ainterpolate).

Comment: I've heard ["interpolate"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13010/dollar-sign-interpolation-inside-quotes-in-bash) being used to refer to what others might call [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). At first, I was going to say, keep dereferencing talk to C and C++ code, but no, they [say it in Bash world too](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/complexfunct.html). So we're all talking about the same thing. +1 for the vote against `expr` though.

Comment: A better word is _expanding_, but not _dereferencing_. _dereferencing_ is used when we use _pointers_, that's not the case here, that's just simple variables.

Comment: @Prashant: tldp is not known to be a good reference in the bash world.

Answer (score 7):

To get the numbers after decimal point, you can do this:-

```
read num1 num2
div=`echo $num1 / $num2 | bc -l`
echo $div
```

Answer (score 1):

let's suppose

```
x=50
y=5
```

then

```
z=$((x/y))
```

this will work properly .
But if you want to use  /  operator  in case statements than it can't resolve it.
[image: enter code here]
In that case use simple strings like div or devide or something else.
See the code

Comment: This is wrong. `/` works fine as a shell-case label. What doesn't work is to use `*` for multiply without quoting it, which might be what you actually did; _that_ causes it to effectively override all following items in the case, which in your example is 'devide' and 'modulo'