# Can't do arithmetic operation in bash

Tags: bash, curl, awk

I'm trying to do the following:

```
size=$(curl -sI "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask" | grep -i Content-Length | awk '{print $2}')
echo $((size / 3))
```

But this returns the error:

```
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

I guess it has something to do with the result of awk.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do division with variables in a Linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093871/how-can-i-do-division-with-variables-in-a-linux-shell)

Comment: Why not do the arithmetic in `awk` at the end of the pipe?

Comment: `curl -sI "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask" | awk '/Content-Length/{print $2/3; exit}'`

Comment: and an `echo "size=${size}ZZZ"` before your calculation to be sure there is only numeric values saved to `$size`. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the carriage return `\r` from the size:

```
size=${size%$'\r'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful function for division I picked previously on another thread:

```
calc() {
awk "BEGIN { print "$*" }";
}
```

End result:

```
calc() {
awk "BEGIN { print "$*" }";
}
size=$(curl -sI "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask" | grep -i Content-Length | awk '{print $2}')
echo "$(calc ${size}/3)"
```

Execution:

```
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/TestStackoverflow$ ./processing.sh 
18758.3
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/TestStackoverflow$
```

Hope it helps!