# Unable to substract two variable in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script that's picking up two values from a file and then subtracting them.But I am unable to do **substraction** as it is throwing error.

```
   res1=  awk 'FNR == '${num1}' {print $1}' /home/shell/test.txt
   res2=  awk 'FNR == '${num2}' {print $1}' /home/shell/test.txt

   res= $((res2 - res1))
   echo $res
```

I also tried `` expr = `expr $res2 -$res1` ``  but it didn't work. please help me so as to get the desired result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract 2 variables in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385627/subtract-2-variables-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your assignments for res1/res2 are wrong.  It should be

```
res1=$(awk 'FNR == '${num1}' {print $1}' /home/shell/test.txt)
```

However, you can do it all in `awk`

```
$ num1=5; num2=2; awk -v n1=${num1} -v n2=${num2} 'FNR==n1{r1=$1;f1=1}
                                                   FNR==n2{r2=$1;f2=1}
                                                    f1&&f2{print r1-r2; exit}' <(seq 5)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is one `space` char after each `=` sign: `res1=  awk`

Remove the spaces and use `$( command )` to execute a command and gather its output.

Give a try to this:

```
res1="$(awk -v num=${num1} 'FNR == num {print $1}' /home/shell/test.txt)"
res2="$(awk -v num=${num2} 'FNR == num {print $1}' /home/shell/test.txt)"
res=$(( res2 - res1 ))
printf "%d\n" ${res}
```

I had read in another answer that it is preferred to pass variable's value to `awk` script using `-v var_name=value`, rather than concatenating strings.