# Linux shell negative values print problem

Tags: linux, shell, echo

```
operation () {
   operator=${exp:1:1} # 2nd character / 1st is ${words:0:1} 

   # Read into an array as tokens separated by IFS
   IFS="$operator"
   read -ra array <<< "$exp" # -ra = raw input array
   a=array[0]
   b=array[1]
   # https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/read.htm

   if [ "$operator" == "+" ]; then
    operation=$((a+b))
   fi
   if [ "$operator" == "-" ]; then
    operation=$((a+b)) # => ' 1'
    operation=`expr a-b` # => ' 1'
   fi
   if [ "$operator" == "*" ]; then
    operation=$((a*b))
   fi
   if [ "$operator" == "/" ]; then
    operation=$((a/b))
   fi
   # https://www.tutorialsandyou.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-arithmetic-operations-11.html
   echo $((operation))
}
exp='2-3'
operation $exp
```

Everything(almost) works fine, just when making the subtraction `operation=$((a+b))` or `` operation=`expr a-b` ``  I cannot print in anyway minus('-') instad of space(' '), the (-) sign it is been replaced by space. In this example I get `' 1'` instead of `'-1'`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `expr a-b` is not the same as `expr "$a" - "b"`. Why didn't you use `$((a - b))` for subtraction?

Comment: I am newbe, thank you for your useful comment =). I have been having problems understanding differences among that kind of expressions. But I am improving,.

Answer (score 0):

use space around - :

```
exp=' 2 - 3 '
```

or

operation = `expr a - b`

or

`COUNT="expr $FIRSTV - $SECONDV"`

also see this [[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385627/subtract-two-variables-in-bash/8385669)][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385627/subtract-two-variables-in-bash/8385669)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But i am still not getting to work this script, even after trying this options. =(

Comment: I send another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant to use `-` if operator is a minus sign:

```
if [ "$operator" == "-" ]; then
    operation=$((a - b)) # => ' 1'
fi
```

There are 2 problems with this script. First, arrays elements are not
referenced like array[0] is in C but `${name[subscript]}` as it says
in man bash:

> Any element of an array may be referenced using  ${name[subscript]}.

So it should be:

```
a=${array[0]}
b=${array[1]}
```

Second, `$((var))` should only be used for arithmetic. If you want to print
contents of variable just do:

```
echo "$operation"
```

All in all, your script should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

operation () {
    operator=${exp:1:1} # 2nd character / 1st is ${words:0:1}

    # Read into an array as tokens separated by IFS
    IFS="$operator"
    read -ra array <<< "$exp" # -ra = raw input array
    a=${array[0]}
    b=${array[1]}
    # https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/read.htm

    if [ "$operator" == "+" ]; then
        operation=$((a+b))
    fi
    if [ "$operator" == "-" ]; then
        operation=$((a - b))
    fi
    if [ "$operator" == "*" ]; then
        operation=$((a*b))
    fi
    if [ "$operator" == "/" ]; then
        operation=$((a/b))
    fi
    # https://www.tutorialsandyou.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-arithmetic-operations-11.html
    echo "$operation"
}
exp='2-3'
operation $exp
```

Usage:

```
$ ./script.sh
-1
```

Comment: I really apologize, I copy/pasted your code and didn't work, maybe there is another situation with my bash installation or something, but thank you very much. =)

Comment: @DiegoMota: what do you mean by `didn't work`?

Comment: @DiegoMota: it works well for me with Bash 5.0.18 and Bash 5.0.3. Make sure you copied it correctly. How do you run it?

Comment: I will check my bash version, I have a file named arithmeticOperations.sh with exactly the same code that I posted. This problem is related to this link (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---arithmetic-operations/problem) and I am trying to solve it according to it. As I told you, I will check my bash version. I run it using 'bash arithmeticOperations.sh'.

Answer (score 0):

We're missing some context here:

- This `a=array[0]` is only correct if `declare -i a`.
- What is `exp`?

But the problem is a simple matter of lack of quoting:

```sh
$ IFS="-"
$ operation="-6"
$ echo $((operation))
 6
$ echo "$((operation))"
-6
```

This is entirely due to the IFS value. bash gets `echo -6` and translates that into `echo "" 6` with the empty string to the left of the `-` delimiter.

Within quotes, word splitting is not performed.

Behaviour documented in [3.5.7 Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) in the manual.

---

You can set IFS only for the duration of the read command so it does not affect the rest of the script:

```sh
$ exp="4-5"
$ IFS=- read -ra array <<<"$exp"
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="4" [1]="5")
$ printf "%q\n" "$IFS"
$' \t\n'
```

Comment: I need a little more time to research on your answer, as I am having problems understanding it. I thank you very much for it, and will write in a couple of days (after research) with some comment.

Comment: Add this page to your research list: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667 -- it focuses on the security implications of quoting, but the intro links to several other questions that are about quoting.

Answer (score 0):

1. I remove this line `operation='expr a-b' # => ' 1'`
2. In this line `operation=$((a+b)) # => ' 1'` you must use - instead + :
3. For output **use "" around the variables**:

`echo "$((operation))"`

This code work properly:

```
operation () {
   operator=${exp:1:1} # 2nd character / 1st is ${words:0:1} 

   # Read into an array as tokens separated by IFS
   IFS="$operator"
   read -ra array <<< "$exp" # -ra = raw input array
   a=array[0]
   b=array[1]
   
   # https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/read.htm

   if [ "$operator" == "+" ]; then
    operation=$((a+b))
   fi
   if [ "$operator" == "-" ]; then
    operation="$((a-b))"
   fi
   if [ "$operator" == "*" ]; then
    operation=$((a*b))
   fi
   if [ "$operator" == "/" ]; then
    operation=$((a/b))
   fi
   # https://www.tutorialsandyou.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-arithmetic-operations-11.html
   echo "$((operation))"
}
exp='2-3'
operation $exp
```