# Linux command to display date in unix format

Tags: linux

What command can I use in linux to display the time in unix format i.e. no of seconds since epoch (01/01/1970)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get current time in seconds since the Epoch on Linux, Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092631/get-current-time-in-seconds-since-the-epoch-on-linux-bash)

Comment: Check the man pages for stuff like this, it'll save you time - looking at `man date` will show you this note: 
`%s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `date` command with format: `date +%s`

Answer (score 4):

Just use this command:

```
date +%s
```

Answer (score 4):

GNU and BSDs:

```
date +%s
```

With most Awk implementations:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{srand(); print srand()}'
```

Probably the most portable out of Linux:

```sh
perl -le 'print time'
```

With shell builtin, ksh93 or Bash 4.1 or above:

```sh
printf '%(%s)T'
```

With shell builtin, zsh:

```sh
zmodload zsh/datetime
echo "$EPOCHSECONDS"
```