# Calendar months variables in BASH script

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a BASH script that calls an API that presents metrics for specific time-frames. I plan to run the script on a cron job on the 1st of each month, the API call needs to contain the start and end time and be in a epoch format with milliseconds. Milliseconds should be ok to set to 000 as it doesnt need to be that specific but the API requires it.

How can I code the script to look at the current human readable time then look at the exact same time exactly 1 calendar month before, then convert both outputs to epoch, and then enter the epoch times in the curl command as a variable?

Example:

Script runs at 1am on July 1st, script then understands a full calendar month before was June 1st, converts both to epoch, places them into the curl command using variables.

I understand how to get a human readable date for 1 month ago, however I am unsure how best to convert these dates to epoch.

```
 date --date="1 month ago" +"%d%m%Y"
```

Comment: date --date="1 month ago" +"%s" should work

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092631/get-current-time-in-seconds-since-the-epoch-on-linux-bash

Comment: I wouldnt say so, mines more specific to the script I am trying to create. Its the conversation into a variable thats part of my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To create a variable using date in epoch times with milliseconds:**

```
ENDDATE=`date +%s%N | cut -b1-13`
STARTDATE=`date --date="1 month ago" +%s%N | cut -b1-13`
```

Use these variables in the cURL command.

Comment: A couple of tips: don't use ALLCAPS variable names; use `$(...)` instead of backticks.