# Best way to compare Timestamps in Linux shell/bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, datetime, timestamp, comparison

I have to read a epoch timestamp (in **seconds**) from a directory `/usr/local/healthcheck.txt` on my Red Hate Enterprise Linux machine every ~10 minutes (polling). I need perform a comparison on the time to check if the timestamp in the `healthcheck.txt` file is OLDER than 50 minutes from the current time/timestamp *OR* if the `healthcheck.txt` is non-existent, to throw an error. The timestamp in the `healthcheck.txt` file generally looks like this (its in **seconds**, as stated above) :

```
1591783065
```

I was using `date -d @1591783065` to convert the timestamp to Human Readable and get something like this:

```
Tue Jun 9 16:22:57 UTC 2020
```

What would be the best approach to compare the current timestamp to this timestamp in the file and check if its older than 50 minutes?

In Java , we have a `Date` package , and can just use `compareTo` to compare the times/dates, is there a simple way to do this with shell/bash scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you stick with epoch-time? You can get the current time as seconds since epoch by 
`date +%s`, so you just have to compare

```
if (( (healthcheck_time + 50*60) < $(date +%s) ))
then
  # .... healthcheck older than 50 minutes
fi
```

Comment: In bash 5 and higher you can use the [built-in `$EPOCHSECONDS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54177664/6770384) instead of `$(date +%s)`.

Comment: @user1934428 I could just  subtract to get the TIME DIFFERENCE like this  $(date +%s) - healthcheck_time, then convert to minutes and check if those MINUTES > 50 then // do some logic , right?

Comment: Sure, but why convert into minutes? In zsh, this might work (but is still unnecessary), but in bash arithmetic, you have only integers, and you would have to do rounding. Therefore I would stick with seconds.