# How to get current time in FILETIME format?

Tags: windows, powershell, filetime, current-time

How can I use PowerShell on Windows to get the current time in the Windows [FILETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) format?

Something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1092643/13112843) about Linux except for Windows, using the Windows `FILETIME` format (64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 UTC), and preferably something simple like the aforementioned answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
# Returns a FILETIME timestamp representing the current UTC timestamp,
# i.e. a [long] value that is the number of 100-nanosecond intervals 
# since midnight 1 Jan 1601, UTC.
[datetime]::UtcNow.ToFileTime()
```

<sup>Alternatives: `[dateime]::Now.ToFileTimeUtc()` or `[datetimeoffset]::Now.ToFileTime()`</sup>

To convert such a `FILETIME` value back to a [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) instance:

```sh
# Creates a [datetime] instance expressed as a *local* timestamp.
[datetime]::FromFileTime(
  [datetime]::UtcNow.ToFileTime()
)
```

Note: The above yields a *local* `[datetime]` instance (its `.Kind` property is `Local`). Append `.ToUniversalTime()` to get a UTC instance (where `.Kind` is `Utc`).

Or, use `[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc()` (note the `Utc` suffix), which directly yields a UTC `[datetime]` instance:

```sh
# Creates a [datetime] instance expressed as a *UTC* timestamp.
[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc(
  [datetime]::UtcNow.ToFileTime()
)
```

Alternatively, use [`[datetimeoffset]::FromFileTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset.FromFileTime) to obtain an unambiguous timestamp, which can be used as-is or converted to a local (`.LocalDateTime`) or a UTC (`.UtcDateTime`) `[datetime]` instance, as needed.

```sh
# A [datetimeoffset] instance unambiguously represents a point in time.
# Use its .LocalDataTime / .UtcDateTime properties to get
# local / UTC [datetime] instances.
[datetimeoffset]::FromFileTime(
  [datetime]::Now.ToFileTimeUtc()
)
```